# Remove given permission to specific device on Android

Tags: android, permissions

I have an application that checks a specific USB device at onCreate event method. When I find my device by looking at its device and vendor id, I'll immidiately ask user for USB permission as belows:

```
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> map = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> it = map.values().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
          UsbDevice device = it.next();
          if (device.getVendorId() == 1155 && device.getProductId() == 22336)
          {
              Log.e("Jetty", "Token found.");
              final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
              PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
              usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
          }
        }
```

Up to now, everything is perfect. If user grants permission, application can communicate with the device. The problem is, every time that the application is launched I'd like to request permission. I mean I don't want to care if user granted the permission or not before. I'd like to ask user again and again at every launch of the application. In short, I want to clear or remove accepted or granted permissions before and ask for it every time.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
mPermissionIntent.cancel();
mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
```

How should I clear the given permissions or solve this problem in another aspect?

Comment: Sorry! I edited the second code block.

Comment: This permission will be cleared if you disconnect the device. Do you still want to clear the permission even if the device still connected to usb?

Comment: @leandrocastelli 
Yes, need to clear permission if usb still attached.